# XCode saying something is potentially insecure for a C program? What exactly does it mean?

Tags: c, xcode

Say we are working in C.

if I go ahead and do this:

```
char *word;
word = "Hello friends";
printf(word);
```

then XCode tells me that because I'm not using a string literal, that I might have something that is potentially insecure. Does that mean an opening for something to hack my program? If so, how could that happen?

Alternatively, if I do this:

```
char *word;
word = "Hello friends";
printf("%s", word);
```

Then XCode raises no flags and I'm fine. What exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `printf` is not the string you want to print.  It's a format string.  It can contain formatting instructions which results in the string that is printed once it is combined with further arguments.

Your first example is [an uncontrolled format string vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string).

Comment: Well, in the example the format string is controlled : it is `"Hello friends"` and cannot be anything else. The message is a false positive  in an uncontrolled format string detection heuristic.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in the first case if `word` contains formatting specs (`%d`, `%f`, `%s`, etc.) then `printf()` will assume those values are on the stack, but in fact they aren't, which could lead to a crash.

Use `puts()` or `fputs()` instead if you don't care about formatting.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm also interested in what the potentially insecure issue might be? What is Xcode referencing?

Comment: Well if the string `word` comes from user input, it's possible to cause the program to crash in such a way that it leaves it open to attack.  If the program is running as `root` then this could mean compromise of the whole system.

Comment: That the compiler warns doesn't mean there _is_ a problem, just that (as the comments and answer say) it _might_ lead to a security problem.